# How to use Python to control Command Prompt application (I/O single terminal)

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to use python's subprocess module to control an application that opens in command prompt. This may involve reading output, but sending several inputs is the priority.

My goal is to use the same cmd terminal multiple times throughout a python program. **Not** to combine commands into a single string and run once.

A simple example of this would be `cd`ing to a directory (say C:/Program Files) in one line of python, and then later calling `cd` to get that directory returned. Here is code for that:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cd C:/Program Files', shell=True, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
a , _ = proc.communicate(input="cd ")
print(a)
```

This code currently prints the empty string `''`. Ideally it would print the return from `input="cd "`.

Comment: what is the return value of cd?
you can check by the print(os.getcwd())

Comment: That returns the folder my script is in.

Comment: it only moves the current folder to the folder you `cd`  on, I think it does not return anything.

Comment: This is on Windows? Its much easier on a linux like system where you can open a pseudoterminal but not with windows that has a different API to run its console.

Comment: Python generally replaces shell scripts. Its worth asking why you'd do something in an interactive terminal when you could just write python.

Comment: This is on windows using window's command prompt. The application I will be controlling is for windows.

Comment: I don't know how about Windows but on Linux you have to use `pwd` to get current folder, and `cd` (without parameters) moves to home folder.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to use some external module - like [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) or [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). OR maybe you should use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) - it can send value to program and wait for expected value.